# useLazyQuery triggered by onChangeText in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I am building an android React Native app with Apollo Client that connects to a GraphQL backend.

I've set up a login screen that users can input their username and password in and execute a login query on click / press of a button.

At first boot of the app (or right after app is refreshed) everything is normal.
Nothing is out of the ordinary when i input the credentials at the first try and log in successfully.
But after one failed login attempt (either by network error or invalid credentials), everytime i type or delete one character from either of the text inputs, the login query from the useLazyQuery gets executed without me pressing the login button.
The problem goes away only when i close and restart the app.

Is onChangeText the cause of this?
Am i not using useLazyQuery correctly?
Am i missing something here?

Here's the code:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { gql, useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext';
import Loading from '../components/Loading';

const LOGIN = gql`
  query Login (
    $username: String!
    $password: String!
  ) {
    login (
      username: $username
      password: $password
    ) {
      token
    }
  }
`;

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const { setAuthLoading } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const nextInputRef = useRef();

  const setToken = async (token) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);
    setAuthLoading(true);
  };

  const [queryLogin, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(LOGIN);
  if (loading) return <Loading />;
  if (error) ToastAndroid.show(error.message, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
  if (data && data.login && data.login.token) {
    setToken(data.login.token);
  }

  const sendLogin = () => {
    queryLogin({ variables: { username, password } })
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        value={username}
        onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
        placeholder="USERNAME"
        returnKeyType="next"
        onSubmitEditing={() => nextInputRef.current.focus()}
      ></TextInput>

      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry={true}
        value={password}
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        placeholder="PASSWORD"
        returnKeyType="done"
        ref={nextInputRef}
        onSubmitEditing={() => sendLogin()}
      ></TextInput>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => sendLogin()}>
        <Text>LOGIN</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Here's my related stack versions:

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.2.1",
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
"graphql": "^15.3.0",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
```

Comment: don't declare variables at hook, pass them within onPress

Comment: @xadm I've tried your advice and the problem still persists but something changed. It doesn't go to the <Loading /> component anymore everytime i type something. So thanks for that.

Comment: why not to use `useMutation` ? why `onSubmitEditing={() => sendLogin()}` ?

Comment: @xadm well the login backend API is a query. I didn't make the backend API. Anyway i changed the method to `useApolloClient` and it worked. Thanks for helping anyway :)